# getting error with freemarker template integration with spring internationlization

Tags: templates, internationalization, freemarker

I am using freemarker template for email generation. I use freemarker in conjunction with spring. I am having a tough time to get internationalization working with parameter substitution. I got it to work for one parameter substitution.
example :

> message.hello = Hello, {0}

in fm template
I have something like

> <@spring.messageArgs "message.hello" name />

however, I am not able to figure out how we do it for multiple param substitution.

> message.greet = Hello {0}, welcome to {1}

how can I represent this in the template?
when I try the following:

> <@spring.messageArgs "message.greet" name, place />

it does not work. could you please help here?
regards

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `spring.ftl` in the Spring source code, that macro is defined as `<#macro messageArgs code, args>${springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code, args)}</#macro>`, which is problematic as `getMessage` in `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext`has several overloads, and you want to call `getMessage(String code, Object[] args)` or `getMessage(String code, List<?> args)`. So you want this:

```
<@spring.messageArgs "message.greet", [name, place] />
```

Note that because there's a `getMessage(String code, String defaultValue)` overload as well, you need to use `[]` even if you have only 1 argument, or else it will be the default.